# Create Read-Only MySQL Database Connection in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-database

Is it possible to add a connection to a database so when using it only select queries are allowed?

Something like this would be great:

```
DATABASES = {
    #can do update, insert, etc...
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '12345',
    }
    #select only
    'default_readonly': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'PASSWORD': '12345',
        'READONLY': True,

    }
}
```

I didn't find anything simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, Django does not provide any options to restrict the database connection to a "read-only" mode. However, you can do it by creating a readonly user in your MySQL database engine.

Another idea, on the Django code side, would be to create your own cursor, which throws exception if `execute` or `executemany` is called. You can look at [this module `django-db-readonly`](https://github.com/streeter/django-db-readonly/blob/master/readonly/__init__.py).

Answer (score 5):

You should set permissions on the user used for the connection (instead of 'root').

This causes insert/update/delete queries raise errors, which you should manage in you views (in needed)

Comment: Thanks Don! However I prefer Maxime solution as it keeps me inside Django (and therefore inside Git)

Answer (score 5):

From Django 1.2 you can specify a Router class to 'route' queries to different databases (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/).

To use one db for read and one for write you can define a Router class like this:

```
Class MyRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default_readonly'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        return db == 'default'
```

And place this in your settings.py

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.MyRouter']
```

This is working for me as long as I don't use select_for_update(), which is considered a read operation, but needs write access to the database. The only workaround I found so far is to override select_for_update in a Manager class in a similar way:

```
class MyManager(Manager):

    def select_for_update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyManager, self).using('default').select_for_update(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Actually I notice that the select_for_update issue is solved in Django 1.7 by considering a select_for_update a write operation.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to make the transaction readonly when the connection gets created in Django's `connection_created` signal.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49753667/15690 for an example with PostgreSQL.